# Why does the last element of an array change?

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
void generate_random_array(int8_t array[], int array_size){
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size + 1; i++){

        array[i] = rand() % 21 + (-10);
        printf("%d, %d\n", array[i], i); 
    }
}


int main(){

    int8_t some_array[100];

    generate_random_array(some_array, 100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
        printf("%d %d\n", some_array[i], i); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program generates random elements of a given array in the range from -10 to 10 and then it displays them. The problem is that the last element of an array changes to 100 when I print elements the second time. I would like to know why.

Comment: Why are you purposefully accessing the array out of bounds? `i < array_size + 1`??  `i < 101;`??? That is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Just a point, please move `srand(time(NULL));` to be the first executable instruction in `main`.

Comment: @ juanchopanza It was not purposefully. It was the mistake that caused the problem. Now it is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @Weather Vane What difference does it make?

Comment: Because if you called `generate_random_array` twice within one second it would (probably, unless the clock ticks between calls) generate the same array.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing of an array starts at zero.

```
int array[3];//  an int array with 3 elements
array[0];    //first element
array[1];    //second element
array[2];    //third element
array[3];    //undefined because it is beyond the end of the array
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function `generate_random_array` you are iterating the `i` upto `array_size + 1`. And you have declared an array of size `100`; `int8_t some_array[100];` OS will reserve the `100*sizeof(int8_t)` bytes memory for you.

Indexes of your array would be lying in range [0,100) ie. excluding the `100th` location.

Now, what you are doing is that you modifying the `some_array[100]` which you have not claimed in your declaration. Its being possible because `C` doesn't do any out-of-bound access checking.

But key point to note is that you are trying to modifying/reading the unclaimed memory. So this is undetermined behavior. It might be possible that you might get different value other than `100`, sometimes.

But all story short, this behavior is undetermined because you are accessing the out-of-bound index of array.

Comment: The official term is _undefined_ behaviour, but +1 anyway for the thorough explanation :-)